# How to add syntax highlighting for new language

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Is there already a standard way for introducing syntax highlighting for a language (and tag) that did not previously have it?

I would like to have syntax highlighting for the [isabelle](/questions/tagged/isabelle) tag, since code is sometimes hard to read without it.

Comment: The likely problem I foresee is that [tag:isabelle] is only used by 24 questions. Though I wonder what the process is on a generic scale...

Comment: Well, my question is for the general case. How would one add syntax highlighting for a new language in general. (Only my motivation is specific to isabelle.) Also I did not expect anybody to write a syntax plug-in, more like, if I had a plug-in how could it be added to SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems to be a rather obscure language. I doubt highlighting will be added for that anytime soon.

Besides, adding highlighting isn't in the hands of SE. SE uses the [Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) engine, which supports the languages listed [here](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html). I guess you could write an extension for it. (Not sure if SE would include it, seems like a lot of overhead for 24 questions)

Comment: I guess my question is in essence, whether SE would include such an extension, if it was provided. And once again, my question is not specific to [tag:isabelle]. (Maybe I should remove that part from the question to improve it?)

Comment: +1 @chris I guess it is a good question with a good answer. The first one might be better without being so specific.

Comment: @chris: I guess they would if there are >1000 good question on the tag. I guess :S